# UITabBarController's TabBar blocking UIViewController that is pushed by UINavigationController it hosts

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController which has 5 tabs. Each of which has host a UINavigationController.

Everything is working well except that everytime each of these UINavigationController push a ViewController. Their bottom part is blocked by the UITabBar. Which is normal.

But i am wondering is it possible to have the UIViewController above the UITabBar?

Any idea how?

Edit:

Here is the structure

```
UITabBarController
    Tab 0: UINavigationController
    Tab 1: UINavigationController
    Tab 2: UINavigationController
    Tab 3: UINavigationController
    Tab 4: UINavigationController
```

So everytime that the NavigationController push a Uiviewcontroller. That UIViewController position is still blocked by the UITabBar since it is below it.

How do I have the UIViewController above the TabBar?

Comment: Can you provide some screen shots or code that can help in determining how the controllers are structured?

Comment: Did you use a storyboard to construct the structure or through code? Did you use autolayout and how are the VC presented, through a navCtrl push?

Comment: I don't use storyboard. Purely code. The behaviour is expected. But I am wondering if there is any workaround to show the ViewController above the UITabBar

Comment: Can you see if my answer below works?

Comment: If you expect it to behave like that either hide the tab bar by or don't use a push from the navCtrlr. I'm not sure if you need the navCtrlrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try doing this and see if it works?

```
destinationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

Do this right before you segue into the destination view controller.

Hope this helps.